# How do I extract data from a json file and output it to txt/json?

Tags: python, json

New to python and working with jsons. I've managed to load all my jsons into a loop and output the location and the value I'm looking for using the print command. But how do I get the username data to be saved into a txt or csv?

My working code:

```
import json
from   pathlib import Path


for f in Path(mypath).rglob('*.json'):
    data = json.loads(f.read_text())
    print(mypath)
    print(data['customer'][0]['lname'])
    f = open("testfile.txt", "a")
    f.write(#i know need to pass something here but no luck)
    f.close()
```

I just want to extract the same value from all my jsons and just output it to a file. Any help?

layout of my jsons:

```
{
    "sheduledTime": "9:30",
    "startDateForStartDate": "01/29/2020",
    "endDateForStartDate": "02/03/2020",
    
    "customer": [
        {
            "fname": "somedata",
            "lname": "somedata",
            "username": "somedata"
        }
    ]
}
``
```

Comment: FYI, you can use load rather than loads. `data = json.load(f)`

Comment: Why not put `data['customer'][0]['lname']` in to the f.write function? This should output the lname field to the file. You'll need to share your JSON file if it is another field you wish to output

Comment: @scotty3785 Thank you, this works but the output of lname is in the same line as the next lname. So it ends up being a whole sentence. IS there a way to display each of the lnames line by line?

Comment: As I said, you'd need to share an example of your JSON data if you want more specific help. Difficult to advise you to break up the lname string if you don't share it's format

Comment: @scotty3785 i've updated the topic with my json layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would implement it. This code reads all user information and writes it into a text file.

```
import json
import os

mypath = "PATH_TO_FOLDER" #path must end with a "/"

for path in os.listdir(mypath):

    if path.endswith(".json"):

        with open(mypath+path, 'r') as file:

            data = json.load(file)

        with open("testfile.txt", "a") as f:

            for key, value in data['customer'][0].items(): # loops through all keys that the customer object has

               f.write(value + '\n')
```

for just the username use this code:

```
import json
import os

mypath = "PATH_TO_FOLDER"

for path in os.listdir(mypath):

    if path.endswith(".json"):

        with open(mypath+path, 'r') as file:

            data = json.load(file)

        with open("testfile.txt", "a") as f:

               f.write(data['customer'][0]["username"])
               f.write("\n")
```

Comment: Why replace `rglob`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer because the sample he provided did not work with r.glob

Comment: I think it would work fine. In any case, the question was about writing to files, not ways to traverse folders.

Comment: so my answer is correct? or did I miss something ?

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege Hi. Thanks for this. This works, but the issue is the taken username is in the same line as the next username. So it ends up looking like "bobjames"

How would I put the next username into the next line? I've tried '/n'

Comment: @LewisGreen your idea was right you just took the wrong symbol. It should be "\n" not "/n". I updated the code so each username is in  a new line :)